# How to achieve "visited recently" using Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to create a list of hyperlinks to the last 5 pages (views) visited by a user. However I don't really know where/ how to start...

I thought about somehow storing each route when visited but I don't know what's the best practice to do so.

I'm not asking for a working code, I just need some help to find the right direction to start with.

Comment: maybe you can have a "history" circular-array in vuex store and you populate it from the router using nav guards?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>{})` and store the url in an array. You can read more details about navigation guards here.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

Answer (score 0):

Found this, it may help:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-glade-qnrxm

It stores the visited routes.
It works like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="crumb in crumbs" :key="crumb.index">
      <router-link :to="crumb.path">{{ crumb.name }}</router-link> |
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      crumbs: []
    };
  },
  watch: {
    $route(to) {
      if (this.crumbs.length > 3) {
        this.crumbs.shift();
      }
      this.crumbs.push({
        path: to.fullPath,
        name: to.name/*  */
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.crumbs.push({
        path: this.$route.fullPath,
        name: this.$route.name
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Here, it gets the route name and path on mount and pushes it to crumbs array.

```
 mounted() {
    this.crumbs.push({
        path: this.$route.fullPath,
        name: this.$route.name
      });
  }
```

Then it constantly watches and changes on route. On change, it shifts(removes the last and adds a new one) any router if there are more than 3. And then it assignes the name and path for every new router.

```
 watch: {
    $route(to) {
      if (this.crumbs.length > 3) {
        this.crumbs.shift();
      }
      this.crumbs.push({
        path: to.fullPath,
        name: to.name/*  */
      });
    }
  },
```

And at last, it loops the crumbs and displays it.

```
   <span v-for="crumb in crumbs" :key="crumb.index">
      <router-link :to="crumb.path">{{ crumb.name }}</router-link> |
    </span>
```

Comment: sunflower seed, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @sta My bad, sorry. I was in a hurry. I will edit.
Thanks.